# Choosing Imagery type for ArcGIS Server (without Image Extension)?

Tags: arcgis-server, imagery

I am exploring the best options to serving raster imagery on ArcGIS Server 10.2.2.

As a background, I currently have roughly 200 .jp2 files of about 3mb each. All of these files are currently served locally via the Mosaic Dataset function. However, Mosaic Dataset is not supported in ArcGIS for Server unless you have the Image Extension (which I do not).

I have used some techniques in QGIS to merge the .jp2 rasters but the size becomes too massive to serve over ArcGIS Server (roughly 20 gb). The merge I have run was for .TIFF and .IMG.

How do I serve multiple .jp2 or condense the .jp2?

Comment: What do the end users need to do with the service? Are they aerials and just need to be used as a reference layer (therefore cached service is fine) or do they need the actual rasters for analysis?

Comment: Hey @Simon the rasters are purely for reference. The aerial images are merely to look at. like google satellite view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JP2 images](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000q000000) can be loaded up into ArcGIS for Desktop, and served up as a cached map service within ArcGIS for Server

> the rasters are purely for reference. The aerial images are merely to
>   look at. like google satellite view

Then there is no need for serving these up as Image services.  This is a common mistake, as people believe that as its imagery, it should of course be served up as an image service.  You should serve these up as a cached map service, choosing the JPG type to create tiles in.

From Esri:

> if the purpose of your imagery is only for visualization as a base
>   layer and you expect moderate to high amounts of traffic on your site,
>   you should attempt to use a cached map service for the imagery. If you
>   want to expose analysis and manipulation of the imagery and you don’t
>   feel that your server will be overwhelmed by concurrent requests, use
>   an image service.

Highly recommend reading [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/05/04/imagery-in-web-applications-should-i-use-a-cached-map-service-or-an-image-service/).

You do mention that you have had some issues with merging the rasters and pulling into ArcGIS for Desktop?  Is there a need to merge the rasters?  You should be able to keep consistent colour ramps across the separate datasets to avoid merging into one file.  I have served up services that contain datasets of this size or larger, just remember to ensure you do not 'copy data to server' and you have the source path of the data registered as a registered data store with ArcGIS for Server

Comment: Hey @Simon, that is an awesome answer - super detailed! my problem lays in that my Jpeg2000 are a bunch of small images sewn together using the mosaic dataset. I have tried to merge all the jp2 using tools in QGIS (GDAL Merge and convert functions) with no luck. your answer takes care of how to get the content online. I am just having troubles with making a series of JP2's into one merged image.